# Implement data in Java without database

Tags: java, data-structures, dataset

I have a set of data which is in short:
person1;age;mark
person2;age;mark
person3;age;mark
..

How can I work with this set of data in java in the same way as in a database, but without using a database?

Comment: You could use a HashMap.  How large is the data set?  If you go over a gigabyte or about one million rows, you're probably better off to actually use a database.

Comment: You cannot - databases can `JOIN` data, they can `INDEX` data, they can from data integrity `CONSTRAINT`s and they support ACID transactions. What exactly is it that you **actually** want to do?

Comment: In-memory is not persistent when the app goes down.  If you want a database, use a database.  Why write all that yourself?

Comment: Do you want to use database without database?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to persist the values only during the life time of the application then you can achieve this by using static lists and singleton object and also hash maps
  but if you want the values even  after the application is restarted then you should go for files.you can have integrity constraints in your code if you use files.

Comment: Data persistence is just one part of a database's roles. Without knowing what the OP wants the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: But in case of files he can have most of the database concepts implemented.

Comment: WHAT? Lets see you implement ACID XA transactions and indexed searches in files. How do you do UPDATEs with files? Sorry - but that is at best an oversimplification, at worst outright wrong.

Comment: Guess I assumed he wanted an alternative to database so as far as I know I could not think of anything better than files and singleton object ? Do you have any other approach ?

Comment: My point is that a database is a **database**. If you need a database, then that is the only option - with very good reason. If you need something else, a subset of database functions, then you need to work out that the subset is. Persistence is one subset. Searching would be another subset. Finally, transactions are probably the most important database role - this cannot be fulfilled without a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not willing to use an external data service, you can use data structures to store data or already available **in-memory data bases like [Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/).**

These data structures can be stored in either in-memory or flat files.
If you consider in-memory storage, in case you need faster write and read consider below:

- If your data can be categorized/descried as key-value pairs, you can
  use, ***maps*** [HashMap, TreeMap, Hashtable, SortedMap]
- If the information in data are like the same, you can use **sets** *[
  Collection, Set]*
- If data are hierarchical, use complex data structures like **java class**
  or **XML objects**, and encapsulation mechanisms of above.
- If the data are unstructured steams, use  **buffers**, **strings**.

Ex:

Create a java class and include it in a set:

```
class Person{
string name;
...
}

set<Person> people;
```

You can insert and retrieve information from your above database [people object]

If the data is too large to store in memory, you may need to consider persiste them in files, but I feel your concern is out of it.